# Estrutura de classes em Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, organização-de-projeto

Olá, a um tempo já venho estudando `asp.net mvc`, e desenvolvendo pequenos projetos, evoluindo e obtendo conhecimento cada dia mais.

Uma dúvida que tenho, e não encontrei muito assunto a respeito na internet, foi sobre a melhor prática para estrutura e organização de pastas e classes em um projeto mvc, cujo essas classes não sejam as de `Model`, e `Controller`. Por exemplo, uma classe de Constantes, ou de utilidades

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode organizar como preferir, só seja consistente na sua escolha de organização em seu projeto. Na realidade, não existe uma forma certa de organizar as pastas e arquivos de um projeto, cada um faz como prefere e como cada situação requer. Procure responder a pergunta: por que organizar por pastas e não deixar tudo jogado na raiz?

A resposta disso, logicamente, é pra você não se perder, pra saber onde está cada coisa de forma rápida para que seu desenvolvimento seja produtivo. É isso que você tem que ter em mente ao criar uma estrutura de pastas. As pastas Models e Controllers existem porque são uteis: seus view models estão na pasta models e seus controllers na pasta controllers - você sabe exatamente onde procurar.

No seu exemplo, você pode criar uma pasta `Utilities` por exemplo e colocar lá dentro suas classes de utilidades. Pode criar uma pasta `Configuration` e colocar suas classes relacionadas a configurações da aplicação. O importante é entender que cada caso é um caso.

Com relação a separação de projetos, acredito que você tem que pensar em uma divisão lógica da sua aplicação e pensar nas coisas que você não quer misturar. Um exemplo simples é você separar um projeto `Aplicacao.Dominio` para codificar o seu modelo de domínio. A motivação para isso é: você não quer misturar o seu código de domínio com seu código de interface de usuário do MVC e ao mesmo tempo você não quer que os tipos de domínio dependam da sua interface.

Essa separação, se feita de forma correta, te permite evoluir o domínio sem mexer no projeto da interface e aí se mostra útil.

Comment: Boa cara, assim a questão de organização de pastas, em projetos webforms, por exemplo eu criava uma pastas AppClass, e dentro dela, colocava minhas classes e se necessários subpastas, para deixar melhor organizado. Mas como estou iniciando em MVC, não sabia se essa seria a melhor opção ou não. Agora com a sua resposta eu já tenho um norte. E @Leonardo, me interessei na questão de projeto Aplicacao.Dominio, tem alguma referência pra me indicar? Quero saber um pouco mais a respeito.